# how can I get the same data from mysql query without run it again use php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Can someone help me find command in php that allow me save mysql query result, and use it again. When I say 'save' I don't mean really save it in the variable or something, and I also don't want run the query again, just use the query's result again. I know that this command exists somewhere, but unfortunately I can't find it..

maybe someone know that specific command? pls help me.

Edit:
I find the command I seek for:
mysql_data_seek()

Comment: What do you mean you do now tan to save the result but you want to use the result of the query?

Comment: something like 'fetchAll()'?

Comment: thanks for comments but I found what I seek: mysql_data_seek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

You will need to move the pointer to the begining of the record set before you can fetch all 
data again. Use mysql_data_seek($result,0);

Answer (score 1):

You have to store it in a variable. That's all.

Comment: what if my table have a lot of rows? why not use "mysql_data_seek"?
I don't want spend resources on big variables..